# Rails | Rescue exception in model and use the error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rescue

I am using the [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem to allow users to post tweets from my app.

This is my tweet.rb file

```
 class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user

     validates :user_id, :tweet, presence: true
     before_create :post_to_twitter

     def post_to_twitter
       begin
        user.twitter.update(tweet)
       rescue Twitter::Error => error
        // I want to do a redirect_to root_path, notice: "Please fix the error #{error.message}"
       // but its against MVC structure to pattern for a model to redirect, since its the task of a controller. How can I achieve this in controller
       end
     end
    end
```

In the rescue block of the post_to_twitter method, I want to do a `redirect_to root_path, notice: "Please fix the error #{error.message}"`
but its against MVC structure to pattern for a model to redirect, since its the task of a controller. How can I achieve this in controller?

This is tweets_controller.rb file

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

      def new
        @tweet = Tweet.new
      end

      def create
        @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
        @tweet.user_id = current_user.id
        if @tweet.save
          redirect_to new_tweet_path, notice: "Your tweet has been successfully posted"
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private
      def tweet_params
        params.require(:tweet).permit(:tweet, :user_id)
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add error to object when callback is not successful:

```
def post_to_twitter
  begin
    user.twitter.update(tweet)
  rescue Twitter::Error => error
    # error will be appear in `@tweet.errors`
    errors.add(:base, "Please fix the error #{error.message}")
    false
  end
end
```

Then, do whatever you need in controller when `@tweet.save` returns `false` (and it will return false since the callback was not successful):

```
def create
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
  @tweet.user_id = current_user.id
  if @tweet.save
    redirect_to new_tweet_path, notice: "Your tweet has been successfully posted"
  else
    # render 'new'
    redirect_to root_path, notice: @tweet.errors.full_messages.join(',')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrey. How can I use that specific error in the controller? current_user.errors.full_messages is empty

Comment: @Mahendhar it is not current user object you are creating, it is `@tweet` object. thus, `@tweet.errors`

Comment: @Mahendhar see the edit. Basically, in model we added the error to `:base`, but you can add the error to any attribute of the object

Comment: Many thanks @Andrey, can u also edit  `# error will be appear in user.errors` line in rescue block.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) in the controller to catch errors:

```
class TweetsController

  rescue_from Twitter::Error, with: :error

  def error
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Please fix the error #{error.message}"
  end
end
```

Additionally if you want to catch the error in both your model and controller you would do it by re-raising:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :tweet, presence: true
  before_create :post_to_twitter

  def post_to_twitter
   begin
     user.twitter.update(tweet)
   rescue Twitter::Error => error
     self.twottered = false
     raise error
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Using validations as suggested by @AndreyDeineko is also an option unless the error is something like a connection error in which case the user cannot fix the problem.